# Nginx case-insensitive filenames

Tags: nginx

I have searched through Stackoverflow and haven't found a solution that appears to work.

I files that use both uppper and down case in their filenames, eg:

> someFileName.php

Then if I browse to https://example.com/somefilename.php I want that file to be served.
In my nginx config I have the following:

```
location ~* \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include       fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass  unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
}
```

From what I understand, the "~*" part should match this case-insensitive, however I still get a 404, because it's trying to find somefilename.php instead.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Comment: This is not an `nginx` issue. Your file system will need to be case insensitive for this to work.

Comment: I realise that this is a filesystem limitation, I was hoping there was a perl solution since Nginx allows for some perl functions. 
I've been thus far unsuccessful in my attempts to make perl "do things".

Comment: Perl or LUA can change the case of the URI to all upper or all lower, but that will not help in this case, where a case sensitive file system is hosting mixed case filenames.